# Invalid field name in query

Tags: ms-access, reference, ms-access-2016

I "inherited" an Access file from my predecessor and I'm trying to update it to represent 2018-19 values instead of 2017-18. However I'm now getting the error message of:

"The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize `'[Historical Quality query].[4/1/2017]'` as a valid field name for expression."

I have updated all of my tables and data to represent 4/1/2018 but I can't find this parameter within the associated query. Even when looking at the tables and fields within the connected query.

Is there a way to find out where this may be hiding? I don't know how to find out where this may be lurking so I can change it to reflect proper dates. I'm hoping someone here may have a method I can use to locate it.

Comment: You can use the database documenter to generate a document with all SQL and VBA in the database, and search that. There are also paid 3rd party tools to search everything.

Comment: Go to queries and find `Historical Quality query`. Select it and then go to database Tools -> Object dependencies. It will show you any objects using this query and in one of those objects you will find the broken reference.

Comment: SunKnight0 - thanks, this did the trick! There were two straggler fields in a database and that seemed to have been stopping it from executing. Thanks!